# AWS Assume Role: "Invalid information in one or more fields."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, assume-role

I am planning to implement AssumeRole scenario so below is scenario

1. user will have ability to create/stop Ec2 instances but not terminate.
2. To terminate he has to assume role (role to be assumed Ec2FullAccess)

I have done the following

1. Create a user ***Test1*** with permission to start/stop/launch Ec2 instance and have provided permission to assume role (EC2FullAccess) below is the Policy for user

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [<br>
            {
                "Action": "ec2:*",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::226904037275:role/EC2FullAccess"
            }
        ]
    }
```

2. Create a role in same account with name EC2FullAccess which would give permission to terminate Ec2 instance
   Ec2FullAccess uses AmazonEC2FullAccess Permission Policy below is its Trust Policy

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when i login as IAM user ***Test1*** and then click on switch role ,i provide below details

Account: 1234
Role: EC2FullAccess

When i click on Switch Role i get Below error
***Invalid information in one or more fields. Check your information or contact your administrator.***

What is that I am missing

Comment: How does `EC2FullAccess` look like? Especially its trust policy.

Comment: I have used AmazonEC2FullAccess Permission policy for EC2FullAccess and i have not edited trust policy i have updated those details in Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the Role this way:

- **Create Role**
- For Type of Trusted Entity, select **Another AWS Account** and enter the Account ID for the *same account* (it is displayed in the same menu as the 'Switch Role' command) -- This might seem odd, but it creates the correct principal in the Trust Policy.
- Attach desired policies and Save

Then, use **Switch Role**.

By the way, assigning `EC2FullAccess` is probably overkill -- it gives permission to do *anything* in EC2, including deleting VPCs, deleting Amazon EBS volumes, changing network settings, etc. I suggest you create a specific policy that grants `TerminateInstances` permission, and possibly even reduce that down to specific instances (eg by tag or VPC).

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. I am newbie to to AWS learning IAM , how do I create IAM policy to give only terminateinstance i cannot just choose ec2:TerminateInstnace. I need to give permission to select AMI Image , can you please let me know how to find all privilege's required to perform an Action, for example for Test1 user i Just want to give permission to only create/Launch instance but when i choose action ec2:startinstance , Test1 user was not able to select AMI . so how do we find all required IAM permission for specific action

Comment: Terminating an instance only requires `ec2:TerminateInstances`. `StartInstance` does not require selecting an AMI. Launching an instance involves quite a lot, such as Security Groups, AMIs, Roles, etc. I don't think there's an easy way to see what is required for that, but there is plenty of information you'll find. Otherwise, just ask.

Comment: I can't believe I wasted so much time on this, because I was using `This account` (assuming that meant it will actually be using the account id). It sounds like `this` actually means `self` in that context, does it not?